# How can I delete rows from related tables in EF 4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So here are 3 tables I'm working with:

[image]

I want to delete everything in the ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXref table and all the related rows in ProcedureCodeModifier from a specific ClaimCodingID.  Here is my code so far:

```
using (HCCustDataEntities hc = new HCCustDataEntities())
            {
                var result = (from CPC in hc.ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXrefs
                              where CPC.ClaimCodingID == claimCodingID
                              select CPC);

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    hc.DeleteObject(item);
                }
            }
```

But only data from the Xref table gets deleted.  Why doesn't EF delete the related rows as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASCADE DELETE` in your relation ship. Entity framework will automaticaly delete the detail / child object when you delete the master record. You dont need to explicitly delete the child records in your relatioship yourself.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work.  Do I have to set up cascading delete in the DB as well?

Comment: @broke: In your EDMX designer, right click on the relationship and set there.

Comment: I still cant get it to work.  Could it be that ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXrefID is the primary key for the Xref table and not ProcedureCodeModifierID?

Comment: @broke: So you want to delete the Parent table when the child being deleted ? If so, change the cascade to `End2 OnDelete`

Comment: Works now after doing a rebuild on the project.  This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have only deleted the CCPCMX row.

This is untested, but it should be something like:

```
using (HCCustDataEntities hc = new HCCustDataEntities())
{
   var result = (from CPC in hc.ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXrefs
                 where CPC.ClaimCodingID == claimCodingID
                 select CPC);

   foreach (var item in result)
   {
      hc.DeleteObject(item);

      var result2 = from pcm in hc.ProcedureCodeModifier
                    where pcm.ProcedureCodeModifierID == item.ProcedureCodeModifierID
                    select pcm;

      foreach (var row in result2)
         hc.DeleteObject(row);

      var result3 = from cc in hc.ClaimCoding
                    where cc.ClaimCodingID == item.ClaimCodingID
                    select cc;

      foreach (var row in result3)
         hc.DeleteObject(row);          
   }
}
```